# Counting A Specific WooCommerce Line Items Against Another One

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I have a list of Orders Items with Custom Attributes as Shown Below (Type Of Waste and Kilogram Of Waste) and I want to count the total kilogram of each waste type. I can access each line item of each order using this code

```
select 
date(pp.post_date),



   sum(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'Kilogram' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END)  as kilogram

from
wp_woocommerce_order_items as p,
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as pm,
wp_posts as pp
 where order_item_type = 'line_item' and
 p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id


select 
date(pp.post_date),



   sum(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'Kilogram' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END)  as kilogram

from
wp_woocommerce_order_items as p,
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as pm,
wp_posts as pp
 where order_item_type = 'line_item' and
 p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id
```

I need to be able to sum of kilogram of up waste type recorded.

In the Woocommerce v3 API, the line items are listed in the endpoint as shown

```
  [{
"id": 881,
"parent_id": 0,
"number": "881",
"order_key": "wc_order_144SFO7qf8uGd",
"created_via": "checkout",
"version": "4.2.0",
"status": "processing",
"currency": "ZAR",
"date_created": "2020-10-15T05:18:40",
"date_created_gmt": "2020-10-15T05:18:40",
"date_modified": "2020-10-15T05:18:40",
"date_modified_gmt": "2020-10-15T05:18:40",
"discount_total": "0.00",
"discount_tax": "0.00",
"shipping_total": "0.00",
"shipping_tax": "0.00",
"cart_tax": "0.00",
"total": "0.00",
"total_tax": "0.00",
"prices_include_tax": false,
"customer_id": 0,
"customer_ip_address": "41.114.213.221",
"customer_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36",
"customer_note": "",
"billing": {
"first_name": "",
"last_name": "",
"company": "",
"address_1": "",
"address_2": "",
"city": "",
"state": "",
"postcode": "",
"country": "",
"email": "",
"phone": ""
},
"shipping": {
"first_name": "",
"last_name": "",
"company": "",
"address_1": "",
"address_2": "",
"city": "",
"state": "",
"postcode": "",
"country": ""
},
"payment_method": "",
"payment_method_title": "",
"transaction_id": "",
"date_paid": "2020-10-15T05:18:40",
"date_paid_gmt": "2020-10-15T05:18:40",
"date_completed": null,
"date_completed_gmt": null,
"cart_hash": "c9761562118fcf129d83dd0c1c38f498",
"meta_data": [
  {
"id": 5922,
"key": "is_vat_exempt",
"value": "no"
}
],
"line_items": [
  {
"id": 34,
"name": "Log EA Dropoff",
"product_id": 213,
"variation_id": 0,
"quantity": 1,
"tax_class": "",
"subtotal": "0.00",
"subtotal_tax": "0.00",
"total": "0.00",
"total_tax": "0.00",
"taxes": [],
"meta_data": [],
"sku": "DRPF001",
"price": 0,
"Kilogram": "",
"key": {...}
}
],
"tax_lines": [],
"shipping_lines": [],
"fee_lines": [],
"coupon_lines": [],
"refunds": [],
"currency_symbol": "R",
"_links": {
"self": [
  {
"href": "https://www.dashboard.kudoti.app/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/881"
}
],
"collection": [
  {
"href": "https://www.dashboard.kudoti.app/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"
}
],
}
}]
```

[image: Order Items With Line Item MetaData]

, I want to be able to count the Kilograms against the type of waste as shown below. I want to query the database in mysql to get a table like this. The data is from WooCommerce and WordPress.

[image: Table I want]

**UPDATE**

Basically what I need to do was an INNER JOIN on the Select on the orderitemmeta and SUM the weight as shown below

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(weight) as total, waste_type
FROM wp_posts as p
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items as oi on p.id = oi.order_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.`order_item_id`, t.`meta_value` as waste_type,  
kg.`meta_value` as weight
FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` AS t
INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` as kg on kg.`order_item_id` = 
t.`order_item_id` AND kg.`meta_key` = 'Kilogram'
WHERE t.`meta_key` = 'Type of waste'
) AS src on oi.order_item_id = src.order_item_id
WHERE p.post_date BETWEEN '2020-04-10 10:42:19' AND '2020-12-10 10:51:34'
GROUP BY CAST(p.post_date AS DATE)
```